# Rails able to find some images in production but not others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I'm running Rails, Puma, Nginx with the standard Rails asset pipeline in production. For some reason though I'm able to display some images and not others.

For example I have two gifs in an /assets/animations folder one displays, the other is giving me an nginx 404 error. I double checked and both files are in my public/assets/animations folder with the correct names and the same file permissions. I can't figure out why this is happening.

*Nginx config*

```
upstream wedding {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:///root/wedding/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
     listen 80;
     server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

     root /root/wedding/public;
     access_log /root/wedding/log/nginx.access.log;
     error_log /root/wedding/log/nginx.error.log;
     index index.html index.htm;

     try_files $uri/index.html $uri @wedding;
     auth_basic off;

     location @wedding {
        proxy_pass http://wedding;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /assets {
        root /root/wedding/public;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

*Update*

On closer inspection the file name that the `image_tag` generates and the file name the assets compiler generates aren't exactly the same -

```
flowers-3866b270148b6759a9307194ba45164405c7dda926f05587f41dfdeada89b80b.gif
flowers-3866b270148b6759a9307194ba45164405c7dda926f5587f41dfdeada89b80b.gif
```

The top one is the file name in the assets folder, the bottom is the one the image_tag is pointing to.

Comment: Are you sure both files are there on the production machine?

Comment: yeah they're both in the public/assets/animations folder on my remote server

Comment: Maybe the file that doesn't display is being affected by a rule in your nginx config.

Comment: @devius I update the question with my nginx config

Comment: I ended up using this gem to disable the digests https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets. Its not ideal but it works

Comment: Weird. Never had this kind of issue. What Rails version are you using?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how that happens. I'm wondering if this warrants creating a second question or maybe filing an issue on the rails github. I'm running rails 5.0.5